# Maven overlay versus maven archetype

Tags: maven

I wanted to know when one would choose to use [Maven overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) and when one would choose to use [Maven archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) as a code reuse technique

Both techniques can be used when you have kind of a "kick starter project" that you want to use across multiple projects.

I could not find a resource which helps you decide which technique to use under a given scenario.

Comment: Overlays isn't some kind of template. *Overlays are used to share common resources across multiple web applications.*

Comment: Thanks for polo ting that out, I meant that both techniques are used to leverage on kick starter projects, have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Archetypes are usually used to generate the basic skeleton of a project. That is used to start a project very fast.

Overlays are used more during the lifecycle of your project. If you have 15 projects that all of them will share some common files (e.g. apache configurations, common classes, etc.) then you will use overlays.

The problem with archetypes is that they are only useful for generating new projects, not for projects already ongoing.